# Keras: How to add computation after a layer and then train model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, theano, keras

I have a question about using Keras (with Theano as my backend) to which I'm rather new. I'm using a many to one RNN (takes in a time series as the input, computes one number as the output) as my first set of layers. So far, this is trivial with Keras using the recurrent layer IO.

Here is where I'm having trouble:

Now I like to pass the output of this RNN (the one number) to a separate function (lets call this f) and then do some computation with it.

What I would like to do is take this computed output (after the function f) and train it against the expected output (via some loss such as mse).

I'd like some advice on how to feed the output post computation from the function f and still train it via model.fit feature in Keras.

My pseudo code is as follows:

```
  X = input
  Y = output 

  #RNN layer 
  model.add(LSTM(....))
  model.add(Activation(...))     %%Returns W*X

  #function f   %%Returns f(W*X)
  (Needs to take in output from final RNN layer to generate a new number)

  model.fit(X,Y,....)
```

In above, I'm not sure how to write code to include the output from function f while it is training for weights in the RNN (i.e. train f(W*x) against Y).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if the RNN's weights should update with the training of f.

**1st option - They should**

As Matias said - a simple Dense layer is probably what you are looking for:

```
X = input
Y = output 

#RNN layer 
model.add(LSTM(....))
model.add(Activation(...))     %%Returns W*X
model.add(Dense(...))
model.fit(X,Y,....)
```

**option 2 - They should not**

Your f function would still be a Dense layer but you will iteratively train f and the RNN separately.

Assuming you have an rnn_model that you defined as above, define a new model f:

```
X = input
Y = output 

#RNN layer 
rnn_model = Sequential()
rnn_model .add(LSTM(....))
rnn_model .add(Activation(...))     %%Returns W*X

f_model = Sequential()
f_model.add(rnn_model)
f_model.add(Dense(...))
```

Now you can train them separately by doing:

```
# Code to train rnn_model
rnn_model.trainable = False
# Code to train f_model
rnn_model.trainable = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a layer to your model that does the exact computation you want. From your comments it seems you just want 
f(W*X), and that is exactly what a Dense layer does, minus the bias term.

So I believe adding a dense layer with the appropriate activation function is everything you need to do. If you don't need an activation at the output then just use "linear" as activation.

Just note that function f needs to be specified as a symbolic function using methods from keras.backend and it should be a differentiable function.